# iOS: Make UIView "Invisible" but not it's Subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

**THE SCENARIO** I am working on a container UIView that will hold controls for a typical video player. The controls will be a PLAY button to play and pause video and a TIME slider to change the position in the video. These controls are added to the container view to then be added *on top* of the player.

**THE ISSUE** When I subclass UIView and make the background color `clearColor`, all I get is a black view that gets added on top of my player. So I can't see the video playing, which is bad.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andMediaType:(MediaType) mediaType {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.controlFrame = frame;
        self.mediaType = mediaType;
    }
    return self;
}
```

**THE QUESTION** How do I subclass UIView to properly make it's background `clearColor` or make it "Invisible" so that it's not covering the Player, **BUT** still have it's subviews (the controls) remain visible over the player?

**ILLUSTRATION**

[image]

**EDIT**

Here is how I'm creating these views. I call them like this:

```
if (!self.player) {
    [self setUpPlayer];
}

if (!self.controlView) {
    [self setUpControlsForPlayerWithType:mediaType];
}
```

And build them like this:

```
-(void)setUpControlsForPlayerWithType:(MediaType) mediaType {

    self.controlView = [[MediaPlayerControlView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.feedImageView.frame.size.width, self.feedImageView.frame.size.height)];
    [self.feedImageView addSubview:self.controlView];
}

-(void)setUpPlayer {

    self.player = [[RTMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithURLString:kSampleMedia];
    self.player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.feedImageView.frame.size.width, self.feedImageView.frame.size.height);
    [self.player setControlStyle:RTMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
    [self.feedImageView addSubview:self.player.view];
 }
```

Comment: If the above doesn't work, try showing us how you're creating an instance of this view.

Comment: @Matt I tried that and it did not fix it. There is still just a black box that covers the entire player. moby I added how I am creating these in my edited question.

Comment: When I've experienced this in the past it's because I've added a viewController not a view. viewController's have black background behind the views you add to them and also you can't see the view controller that is underneath it.

Comment: Ok. All this just because I didn't use the right init method. I created a custom init method `initWithFrame: andMediaType:` and code complete made me write out just the out-of-the-box `initWithFrame:` and I didn't have that definition in my UIView class. Therefore it was not getting called. Damn autocomplete...